# How to update position of list item in jquery ui sortable using php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am new to jquery sortable so referring this tutorial.

http://codingpassiveincome.com/jquery-ui-sortable-tutorial-save-positions-with-ajax-php-mysql

but above tutorial demonstrate sort list item in single div i.e item will be sort(change its position) within same div, but my requirement is to sort list item from first div to second div,similarly move item from second div to 3rd div.
but in my case all 3 div are side by side and have same id, so how to work with jquery sortable using php ajax with multiple div (div are side by side)

```
Html code:

<div>                       <div>                      <div>           
<ul id="sortable1">          <ul id="sortable1">         <ul id="sortable1">
<li>list item 1</li>          <li>list item 11</li>       <li>list item 21</li>  
<li>list item 2</li>          <li>list item 12</li>       <li>list item 22</li>
<li>list item 3</li>          <li>list item 13</li>       <li>list item 23</li>
<li>list item 4</li>          <li>list item 14</li>        <li>list item 24</li>
</ul>                        </ul>                       </ul>
</div>                      </div>                      </div>
```

Comment: does it have to be jquery ? why do you not use php instead of jquery if you dont mind !?
do you want the sort be by name ?

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa  I want to update using php and ajax

Comment: but I am new to this so don't have that much idea

Comment: you need to define diff id for all ul, and use connecwith [like here](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) and then you have to check the position, to, from, etc

Comment: can you please share  me link for any source code

Comment: i have added as answer, if you need more explanation let me know,

Comment: @AhmedSunny shall i store position of every item  in single table or different table because I have 3 separate div

Comment: I need more expanation about this ,it is completely new things for me so facing difficulties to understand this concept

Comment: how is your data , how are loading them right now? and how is it in db, share this in your question

Comment: just now i have started this,simply no idea for   further steps I got stuck there

Comment: have you tried the code, which is available in the tutorial, it depends on how is your data if they belong to same table , then you can have a position stored in one column and if not then different, or you can store position and also the column(div) , and if its drag from one div to another then change the div value .

Answer (score 1):

you can look at the following code, i had the same case so i made something like this, as you have different events available which you can use your way,

the dnd() function is just drag and drop, you can call it with all your ids comma separated like

```
dnd('#sortable_1,#sortable_2,#sortable_3')
```

the function will initialize the sortable and also drag and drop,

the ajax calls are upto you, you can have one or anyway you want, for my scenario i had 2 different, because i save the order in db, and i have many sortable items in my view, and i have different type of data , means in same list i have data from 2 3 different db tables, its for your understanding so,use it you own way

```
<script>
 function dnd(all_ids) {
        var scrollTo = null;
        var adjustment;
        var fromposition = toposition = from = to = type = taskid = istask = '';
        var adjustment;
        $(all_ids).sortable({
            scroll: true,
            scrollSensitivity: 100,
            scrollSpeed: 60,
            helper: 'original',
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                fromposition = ui.item.index();
                from = $(this).attr('data-fromid');
                type = $(event.target).attr('data-type');
                taskid = $(ui.helper[0]).attr('data-taskid');
                istask = $(ui.helper[0]).attr('data-istask');
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {
                to = $(event.target).attr('data-fromid');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
//                console.log('end');
                /* Send JSON to the server */
                // this is just to show, how you get all items if you want 
                var id_array = [];
                var sort_array = [];
                $(ui.item).parent().find('li').each(function () {
                    sort_array.push($(this).attr('data-hwforder')); // these are my custom data attr
                    id_array.push($(this).attr('data-taskid'));
                });
                sort_array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
                // end 
                // dragtype and drag are also custom variables, 
                if ((from !== to) && type && from && to) {
                    // different column
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/update-different-column",
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {from: from, to: to, fromposition: fromposition, toposition: toposition, type: type,
                            sort_array: sort_array, drag: 'crosscolumn', drop_type: 'column'},
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            // success
                        }
                    });//ajax end
                } else {
//                  same column
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/update-same-column",
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {from: from, to: to, fromposition: fromposition, toposition: toposition, type: type,
                             sort_array: sort_array, drag: 'column'},
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            // success
                        }
                    });//ajax end
                }

            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

I hope it is helpful.